# Is ViewState Dictionary type declared as static?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

Can I say that ViewState variable is equivalent to Dictionary type declared as static:

```
ViewState["clicks"] <=> static Object clicks = new Object();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `ViewState` is definitely not `static`. It is an instance property of `Control` (see [`Control.ViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), and can change on every page and on every load of the same page.

`static` variables in ASP.NET are quite dangerous if they contain personal data, since they are shared across all sessions, so you really don't want `ViewState` information to be static.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the [`Control.ViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.110).aspx) property? It's not static, and it's a [`StateBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.statebag(v=vs.110).aspx).

`StateBag` implements the non-generic `IDictionary` interface